# javascript how modify table cell

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple table in HTML and I'm trying to edit a particular cell containing a number.
My arrays all have data in them and the table is created OK.
I want to have an edit box for the number in row3 col 2.
I have tried lots of things but nothing seems to work for me.
Needless to say I am a newbie at JS !!
Thanks,
Chris
Update - I have cracked it! more by luck than judgement.
This code does exactly what I want, but I'm finding it difficult to display for you. It works fine on codepenio.

```
<p id="dt"></p>
<table id="myTable">
  <caption>Current values</caption>
  <tr>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>value</th>
    <th>units</th>

  </tr>

</table>

<!--
<input type="button" onclick="createRow()" value="Create Row" />
  -->
<style>
  table {
    width: 400px;
  }

  th {
    text-align: center;
  }

  table,
  th,
  td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-collapse: collapse;
  }

  th,
  td {
    padding: 5px;
  }
</style>
<script>
  let numberOfrows = document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length;
  let numberoftds = document.getElementById("myTable").rows[0].cells.length;
  document.getElementById("dt").innerHTML = Date();
  // All names including blanks are placed in array below P01 - P30 incl
  pname_english =
    "#cabinet model#Serial number#Face velocity#Face velocity alarm setpoint?#Laminar flow velocity#Laminar flow velocity alarm point?#Extract volume#Extract volume alarm point?#Filter pressure#Filter pressure alarm point?#filter saturation value#Hydrocarbon filter monitor#Formaldehyde filter condition monitor#UV tube hours run#Cabinet hours run#service due date#main carbon filter type#main carbon filter date fitted#";
  let pnamearray = "pname_english";
  pnamearray = pname_english.split("#");
  name = "#p01AB200#P021234#P033.4#P041.2#P054.2#P064.8#P072.9#P083.2?#p092332";
  let myarray = "name";
  myarray = name.split("#");
  units = "# # #m/s#m/s#m/s#m/s#Pa#Pa?# ";
  let unitsarray = "units";
  unitsarray = units.split("#");
  console.log("Hello World!");
  let col1 = "";
  let col2 = "";
  let col3 = "";

  function createRow() {
    //() causes the function to execute anyway!
    var row = document.createElement("tr"); // create row node
    col1 = document.createElement("td"); // create column node
    col2 = document.createElement("td"); // create second column node
    col3 = document.createElement("td"); // create second column node
    row.appendChild(col1); // append first column to row
    row.appendChild(col2); // append second column to row
    row.appendChild(col3); // append second column to row
    //    col1.innerHTML = ""; // put data in first column
    //    col2.innerHTML = ""; // put data in second column
    col3.innerHTML = ""; // put data in second column
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable"); // find table to append to
    table.appendChild(row); // append row to table
  }
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
  let l = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    // add i rows to myTable
    l = myarray[i].length;
    col1.innerHTML = pnamearray[i]; // name column
    col2.innerHTML = myarray[i].substring(3, l); //value column myarray[i];
    col3.innerHTML = unitsarray[i]; //units column
    if (i == 3) {
      col2.innerHTML =
        '<input type="number" id="tentacles" name="tentacles" min="10" max="100" value="20">';
    }
    createRow(); // create new row
  }
</script>

</body>
```

Comment: Please update the snippet I've added to include a sample array.

Comment: You should also include `createRow()` since it may be the better place to do your editing.

Comment: `myarray`,`pnamearray`, `unitsarray` nothing exist !   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @user1504343, your edit removed the demo snippet I had created earlier. Please revise again to put your code in a demo using the editor. We can't help unless we can see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("Table_ID").rows[YourRowIndex].cells.item(CellIndex)
```

RowIndex: Start from 0 to n-1( n is number of rows)

CellIndex: Start from 0 to m-1( m is number of cells per each row)

Comment: For some reason the website wont accept all my code - It works fine on codepen io. There's the arrays anyway! Sorry - I dont often post.

Comment: I do hope that this helps others. Thanks again all of you. Chris

Comment: I used this code many time, you're welcome.